# Json field in Mysql display in Twig but empty in Controller

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have a problem to use json variable in Controller.
I have an entity with a json field :

```
* @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
*/
 private $tagsEntiteMere = [];

public function getTagsEntiteMere(): ?array
{
   return $this->tagsEntiteMere;
}

public function setTagsEntiteMere(?array $tagsEntiteMere): self
{
   $this->tagsEntiteMere = $tagsEntiteMere;

   return $this;
}
```

The Mysql Datatable contain :
`{"tagsGroupe": ["tag1", "tag2"]}`

In my twig template no problem : i can display, tag1 and tag2 with a basic code :

```
{% for tag in app.user.entiteActive.tagsEntiteMere.tagsGroupe %}
  {{tag}}
{%endfor%}
```

But in my controller, the variable is empty :

```
$tags = $entite->getTagsEntiteMere();
print_r($tags);
```

... this code show :
`Array()`

So I don't understand why in twig the variable contain value off Mysql datatable but in controller the same variable is empty.

Have you any ideas ? How solve it ?

Comment: What is the output if you use dump() instead of printer()

Comment: Instead of `private $tagsEntiteMere = [];` have you tried `$tagsEntiteMere;` only. Maybe because you set it in the class it reads it by default as empty array.

Comment: The Result of var_dump @Jeroen : `array(0) {
} `

Comment: @Slavian With online $tagsEntiteMere : variable return "null"...

Comment: @raph Are you sure you are connected to the DB and you query the entity?

Comment: @Slavian when I assign a twig variable from the controller, in twig the dump result contain : tagsEntiteMere:
 `array:1 [
    "tagsGroupe" => array:2 [
      0 => "tag1"
      1 => "tag2"
    ]
  ]`
But in controller, the variable "tagsEntiteMere" seem to be empty...

Comment: I find something : 
wHen i change the getter : 
 `public function getTagsEntiteMere(): ?array
    {
        //return $this->tagsEntiteMere;
        return array('tagsGroupe'=>array('tags1','tags2'));
    }`
The controller return the good variable :
`array(1) { ["tagsGroupe"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "tags1" [1]=> string(5) "tags2" } }`
The problem is between Doctrine and Controller. But why twig can display this ?